# Why are some of my CQWPs coming back blank for Visitors?

Tags: content-query-web-part

I have a page with approx twenty CQWPs on them, all coming from the same library.  It looks fine to me (Admin) but for the Visitor permission group, some boxes are coming up blank - no error message, just nothing! The header is still there and there is no error message. I've checked the library documents and there are no permission problems, and when I recreate one of the blank CQWPs (new web part with the same search parameters and display settings) the Visitor is still unable to see them.  This does not appear to be a problem with web parts not set up with these settings.  I'm at a loss!  Grateful for any help.

[image: Image of web parts showing 'blank' web parts as well as correctly showing webparts]

Comment: I'd check the permissions on the e.g. Advance decision instructions.  On your CQWP page you have a Visitor group - does this group (the people in this group) have permissions to see documents in the Advance decision instructions document library?

Comment: Hi Tally!  I checked the library and all the documents have the correct audience assigned to them.  That Visitor group also has permission to view that library.  It does appear to be a problem for the read-only group, although they can access the documents if you send them a link.

Comment: Are you using Audiences? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/target-files-news-and-pages-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293  (sorry to be pedantic, but I thought I'd better check since Audience targeting could be another factor in no results showing).  Perhaps you meant user groups.

Comment: Apologies, I should have been clearer (I think I tend to conflate the two!)  So the Audience is set to the same two groups on every document.  I had a look at the library Audience settings and "Enable audience targeting" is not checked.  The users are all in the same permission group.  Thank you for sticking with this, I appreciate it!

Comment: If this data is coming from library there might be chance someone changed permissions of particular documents (item level permissions) by breaking inheritance. In that case even when the visitors has access on document library and not on particular document then they will not be able to see it.

Comment: Try to check the item level permissions for the document you are able to see and others don't to check if this is the issue.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, thank you for your wisdom!  You've sparked an idea in me, I'll get back to you and let you know if it's right!

Comment: Hi all, thanks so much for your advice, I really appreciate it!  It turns out there is something odd going on in the permissions, and you were all completely correct.  Thanks again!

Comment: So I thought I'd come back and update you all since it is a very silly thing - I was using the 'check in' box in the ribbon to do a sort of 'mass check in' but guess what!  It only checks in, it doesn't 'publish as major version', so it wasn't pulling through to the CQWP for Visitors as it was a minor version, which they can't see. So that's what was wrong!  Stick like six forks in me, I am done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I thought I'd come back and update you all since it is a very silly thing - I was selecting a bunch of documents and using the 'check in' box in the ribbon to do a sort of 'mass check in' but guess what! It only checks in, it doesn't 'publish as major version', so it wasn't pulling through to the CQWP for Visitors as it was a minor version, which they can't see. So that's what was wrong! Stick like six forks in me, I am done.